# soliciting exegesis of aphorisms or other exerpts from texts?

Tags: discussion

In particular I have in mind aphorisms from Nietzsche. I can personally say this would be of significant benifit to myself and my studies.

I would envision a question taking such a form as:

Does this mean ... ? How is this connected to ... ? Is this consonant with ... ? etc.

Question titles would look like: 'exegesis of ... from ...'

there would have to be at least a minimum degree of specificity in what is being looked for, and I think it would be expected that questions like this would be accompanied by an interpretation of the meaning, links or implications by the person asking, which would designate the direction which answers should follow.

Any feedback appreciated ;)

Comment: the reason i ask is it's close to asking for opinions, wondering what others think,

Answer (score 2):

My thought on this is that framing this as a reference request would be a better angle. I think asking people for their *own* exegesis is opening up a can of worms that SE tends to prefer to keep a lid on.

Reference requests, though sometimes frowned upon, are (in my mind) a perfectly legitimate type of question. So, you might ask "Is there any secondary literature that discusses #this# Nietzsche aphorism?".

I, at least, would be perfectly accepting of such a question.

Comment: Thanks for the input :)